# Inequality in proof of Taylor polynomial for functions of 2 variables

Tags: inequality, taylor-expansion

I have this inequality that bothers me:

\begin{equation}
|g(h,x)|\le\bigl|o(\sqrt{h^2+k^2})\bigr|\cdot(|h|+|k|)
\end{equation}

where $g(h,k)=f(x+h, y+k)-f(x,y)-df(x,y)-\frac{1}{2}d^2f(x,y)$.
So, since I'm trying to verify Taylor for real-valued functions of two variables, I want 
\begin{equation}
\frac{g(h,k)}{h^2+k^2}\to0
\end{equation}
as $(h,k)\to(0,0)$.
But once I got to the inequality I can't understand how, from that, you can get to:
\begin{equation}
\frac{|g(h,k)|}{h^2+k^2}\le\frac{\bigl|o(\sqrt{h^2+k^2})\bigr|}{\sqrt{h^2+k^2}}
\end{equation}
which is my thesis. 
I tried various ways but I always got stuck.

My attempt. If I am not mistaken, the little-o should "eat" $(|h|+|k|)$:
\begin{equation}
|g(h,x)|\le\bigl|o(\sqrt{h^2+k^2})\bigr|
\end{equation}
But then I got stuck because, for $h^2+k^2<1$, 
\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{\sqrt{h^2+k^2}}\le\frac{1}{h^2+k^2}
\end{equation}
and I got the opposite!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You really won't be able to prove what you want, unless you first rewrite $g(h,k)$ as follows:
$$
g(h,k)=f(x+h, y+k)-f(x,y)-d_{(x,y)}f(h,k)-\frac{1}{2}(h,k)^tH_{(x,y)}(h,k),
$$
where $H_{(x,y)}$ is the Hessian of $f$ at $(x,y)$ and where $(h,k)^t$ is the transpose of $(h,k)$. After this change all should come naturally.

*Added:*
Since you say that this is what you did, then note that
$$
|h|+|k|\le 2\sqrt{h^2+k^2},
$$
which implies that
$$
\begin{split}
\frac{\bigl|o(\sqrt{h^2+k^2})\bigr|\cdot(|h|+|k|)}{h^2+k^2}
&\le \frac{\bigl|o(\sqrt{h^2+k^2})\bigr|2\sqrt{h^2+k^2}}{h^2+k^2}\\
&=\frac{2\bigl|o(\sqrt{h^2+k^2})\bigr|}{\sqrt{h^2+k^2}}\to0
\end{split}
$$
as $(h,k)\to(0,0)$.

Comment: Thank you for your reply but I don't understand. I already wrote g(h,k) as you said. In fact, I used it to got to the inequality above. According to my book from that inequality you can have the thesis just manipulating the inequality itself, just with a simple step. Which is the step I'm missing. :(

Comment: I see. Then all is fine, see my answer for the details that you need.

Comment: Thank you Jonas! It was really simple but I couldn't see it. You saved my day! :)